# How to filter out devices on Google Play with Legacy Camera Hardware Level

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

When using Camera2 API or CameraX I get such crashes for

[image]

[image: 2]

and also

[image]

With Camera 2 API you can check the camera hardware level:

```
val level =
    getCameraCharacteristics(
        context,
        cameraIdx
    ).get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL)
```

and available levels are :

```
CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY
CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LIMITED
CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL
CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_3
CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_EXTERNAL
```

The issue happens only for devices `INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY`, though not for all devices of this level.

The only fix is to use legacy camera API for legacy level

Even `CameraX` uses `Camera2` for all devices and ignores hardware level, so it's useless...

For filtering out devices I found only

The only one I could use is `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.level.full" android:required="true" />` but in this case it will filter all devices with camera hardware levels like 3, limited, external I guess as well, so not just legacy level

What is the solution? I don't want to implement both APIs (legacy camera + camera2), just the Camera2 and exclude devices with legacy camera hardware level